# Animation not working with THREE.JSONLoader and THREE.MorphAnimMesh

Tags: three.js

I exported an animated model from Blender 2.65 to JSON format, with bones and all, using the latest Blender Exporter from Three.js (2013-01-15).

The model is showing fine but the morphTargets does not. There should be a nod of the head.

I tried different way of animating, changing the morphTargetInfluences manually or trying to export with different options, but nothing worked.

I also tried replacing my model with the ones from the Three.js examples (monster and ogro) and they work fine. But comparing the json files, I can't see what's wrong with mine.

Here's the demo : http://lastgolem.com/stackoverflow/
And the Blender file : http://lastgolem.com/stackoverflow/sheppard/sheppard.blend

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by trying different export options again, with the Blender export plugin. 
Here's what worked for me :

- Under "Geometry", I checked "Vertices", "Faces", "Normals".
- Under "Materials", I checked "UVs", "Colors", "Materials".
- Under "Settings", Align mode is set to "None", "Flip YZ" is checked
  and scale is at 1.00
- In the "Experimental" section, under "Animation", I checked "Morph
  animation" and set "Frame step" to 1.00
- In the "Experimental" section again, under "Settings", I checked "All meshes".

All the other settings are unchecked.